# Icons become program tabs when the program runs (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, quicklaunch

Why do icons in quick launch bar (bottom left) become program tabs when the program runs? I can't just left click on them to open a new instance, I have to right click and search the menu for the option. Why does this happen and how to make icons stay?

I put some screenshots to make it clearer:

[image]

---

[image]


**OS:** Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Comment: "Why do icons in quick launch bar (bottom left) become program tabs when the program runs?" - It was programmed to do this.

Comment: Another computer, same OS: https://pasteboard.co/GFW0GtP.png